# Camera 2 Api Error - the error that does not take pictures

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am having an issue with the Camera 2 Api.

When I try to take a picture it would not function. The system would not crash. The error only occurs when I try to take a picture.

Furthermore, I took all the permissions that I need in another activity.

The following error occurs.

```
      Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"
```

I do not know if it has a relation with the error. Please use it as a reference.

**I know that there are similar questions, but neither worked.**

I deleted some codes. If you have any inconvenience please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

```
public class Camera extends AppCompatActivity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener, 
ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

private AutoFitTextureView mTextureView;
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_SAVE_IMAGE = 1002;

private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH = 2220;
private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 1080;
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}
private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);
private String mCameraId;
private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;
private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;
private CaptureRequest mPreviewRequest;
private int mSensorOrientation;
private ImageReader mImageReader;
private Size mPreviewSize;
private File mImageFolder;
private Byte bytes;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private File mFile;



 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
    Button button02 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_take_picture);
    button02.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick (View view){
                                        takePicture();
                                    }
                                }
    );
} 

}
private void setUpCameraOutputs ( int width, int height){
    Activity activity = this;
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                    = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

            Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
            if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                continue;
            }

            mCameraId = cameraId;

            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(
                    CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            if (map == null) {
                continue;
            }

            Size largest = Collections.max(
                    Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                    new CompareSizesByArea());

            int displayRotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
            boolean swappedDimensions = false;
            switch (displayRotation) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270) {
                        swappedDimensions = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180) {
                        swappedDimensions = true;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            Point displaySize = new Point();
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
            int rotatedPreviewWidth = width;
            int rotatedPreviewHeight = height;
            int maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.x;
            int maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.y;

            if (swappedDimensions) {
                rotatedPreviewWidth = height;
                rotatedPreviewHeight = width;
                maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.y;
                maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.x;
            }

            if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {
                maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;
            }

            if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT) {
                maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
            }

            mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                    rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth,
                    maxPreviewHeight, largest);

            int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                        mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            } else {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                        mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            }

            return;
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
}

protected void takePicture () {
    if (null == mCameraDevice) {
        Log.e("Camera", "cameraDevice is null");
        return;
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }else{
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"We need your permission to record and save image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
    }

    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

    try {
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraDevice.getId());
        Size[] jpegSizes = null;
        if (characteristics != null) {
            jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        }
        int width = 640;
        int height = 480;
        if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
            width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
            height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
        }
        final ImageReader mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 2);
        List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<>(2);
        outputSurfaces.add(mImageReader.getSurface());
        outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

        //Callback that is called when a new image is available from ImageReader
        ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                Image image = null;
                //try {
                mFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "sample.jpg");

                ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                buffer.get(bytes);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
                try {
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                    fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    mImageReader.close();
                    if (null != fileOutputStream){
                        try {
                            fileOutputStream.close();
                        }catch (IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        };


        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, null);
        final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener =
                new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                        Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "Saved:" + mImageReader, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        createCameraPreviewSession();

                    }
                };
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                try {
                    session.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), captureListener, null);

                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {

            }
        }, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void createCameraPreviewSession () {
    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }

                        mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        try {
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

                            mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                    null, null);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(
                            @NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    }
                }, null
        );

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        createCameraPreviewSession();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
        Log.d("debug","Camera error");
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;

    }

};

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void openCamera ( int width, int height){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"No permission to open camera",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
        return;
    }

    setUpCameraOutputs(width, height);
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
        }
        manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to request for the camera permission as the first thing before trying to take the actual picture? Maybe this is the reason it's crashing.

Remove this permission part from your method **"take picture"**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    return;
}else{
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"We need your permission to record and save image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
}
```

You could execute it first before calling **take picture**

Comment: Thank you for you response. It looks like the  Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list" was solved.